# executeUpdate() returns always 1 with MERGE statement

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, merge

ExecuteUpdate() is always returning 1. Pls suggest and appreciate any input.

Procedure:

```sql
PROCEDURE INSERT_USER_PREFERENCES(owner_id_var varchar2, stripeid_var varchar2, type_var varchar2, metadata_var CLOB) AS
BEGIN
    MERGE INTO CXO_USER_PREFERENCES d
    USING(SELECT stripeid_var id FROM dual) s
    ON (d.stripe_id = s.id)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (OWNER_ID, STRIPE_ID, PREF_TYPE, METADATA, CREATED_DATE )
        VALUES(owner_id_var, stripeid_var, type_var, metadata_var, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

    COMMIT;
END  INSERT_USER_PREFERENCES;
```

Java code:

```java
try (CallableStatement stmt = connection.prepareCall(CREATE_USER_PREF_SQL)) {
        SQLParameterMapper sqlParamMapper = new SQLParameterMapper(CREATE_USER_PREF_SQL);
        sqlParamMapper.setString(stmt, ":ownerId", userName);
        sqlParamMapper.setCharacterStream(stmt, ":metadata", reader, metadata.length());
        sqlParamMapper.setString(stmt, ":stripeId", stripeId);
        sqlParamMapper.setString(stmt, ":type", userPreference.getType());

        // invoke the database
        int value = stmt.executeUpdate();
        return value;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw e;
    }
```

`stmt.executeUpdate()` -  always returns 1, even though insertion happens only once. Appreciate any inputs on this. Ideally, if there are no insertions or errors, it should return 0 or any exception trace. Pls, suggest.**

Comment: Maybe you made a mistake when you copied your code to your question but the MERGE statement, in the PL/SQL procedure, is missing a WHEN MATCHED clause. That means the MERGE only ever performs an INSERT. You wrote in your question that only one INSERT is performed. Hence I would say you have answered your own question.

Comment: Thanks. Is the WHEN MATCHED clause mandatory? Here, I wanted to insert the record in the database when It is NOT MATCHED. So what is happening now: 1. If the record is inserted into the tables, the stmt.executeUpdate() returns 1 and next time when it checks and founds that record exists for the (d.stripe_id = s.id) and the record will not be inserted into the database but  stmt.executeUpdate() still returns 1. Am I missing something here? Pls, suggest.

Comment: I don't know Java but are you sure the return value from `executeUpdate()` is the number of rows merged? I can't see how it could know that. Surely all it knows is it has successfully called a procedure. Even if it was checking `sql%rowcount` after the call, that would be overwritten by the `commit`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Here what I am looking for is: Let's say I have 2 VM's(Virtual Machine)/2 users, trying to insert the record at the same time. When User1 tries to insert the record in the table: the query should check whether the record exists or not and then allow the user to insert it. In meanwhile if user2 tries to insert, he should not be allowed to. To be more precise, something which helps to stop concurrent insertion into the table. Thanks, looking forward to inputs on this. @WilliamRobertson

Comment: Perhaps the procedure should return the number of rows merged via an OUT parameter.

Comment: Thanks, @WilliamRobertson , Will try it.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Hi, I tried the OUT parameter but ending up with the error "java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed: Ordinal binding and Named binding cannot be combined!" All seems to be okay, can you pls help.

Comment: PROCEDURE TEST (mergedRows OUT NUMBER , owner_id_var varchar2, stripeid_var varchar2, type_var varchar2, metadata_var CLOB) AS
    BEGIN
        MERGE INTO CXO_USER_PREFERENCES d
        USING(SELECT stripeid_var id FROM dual) s
        ON (d.stripe_id = s.id)
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT (OWNER_ID, STRIPE_ID, PREF_TYPE, METADATA, CREATED_DATE )
            VALUES(owner_id_var, stripeid_var, type_var, metadata_var, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
        SELECT count(1) into mergedRows FROM CXO_USER_PREFERENCES WHERE STRIPE_ID=stripeid_var;
        COMMIT;
    END TEST

Comment: java side i am doing as :      try (CallableStatement stmt = connection.prepareCall(CREATE_USER_PREF_SQL)) {
            SQLParameterMapper sqlParamMapper = new SQLParameterMapper(CREATE_USER_PREF_SQL);
            sqlParamMapper.registerOutParameter(stmt, "mergedRows", OracleTypes.NUMBER);
            sqlParamMapper.setString(stmt, ":ownerId", userName);
            sqlParamMapper.setString(stmt, ":stripeId", stripeId);
            sqlParamMapper.setString(stmt, ":type", userPreference.getType());
            int value = stmt.executeUpdate();
            return value;
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can make the column a primary key. Now when multiple VM's tries to execute, the other one will throw a Unique Integrity exception and in the catch block, we can read the SQLException. Once we read the SQLException, we can also read the sqlstate and we can perform the needed operations based on the sqlstate.

Sample code below

```
     if (e instanceof SQLException) {
            String sqlState = ((SQLException) e).getSQLState();
            if (sqlState.equalsIgnoreCase("08000") || sqlState.equalsIgnoreCase("08006")) {
                logger.error("POD DB is down with the sql state:" + sqlState);
                return true;
            }
        }
```